# How to do global replace with -replace in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace

I am new to Powershell, so please understand.

I have this pattern

`(.*?)(\d{3})(.*?:\r?\n)(?!\2)(\d{3})`

to match this text:

```
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
123 is different from:
567.
```

This only gives 1 match, whereas there are 2 instances there. How can that be achieved? The pattern consumes `123` in the first instance so that it can't be found.
I had to repeat the line several times to overcome this. I believe there are other ways. Please help.

Tried to change the `123` pattern into lookahead. But I couldn't capture the `123`.

Goal: I want to insert a line, a sentence, between the two different values.

EDIT: like this

```
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
   *** This value 123 ***
123 is different from:
  *** This value 567 ***
567.
```

Comment: Your pattern does not seem to match anything, see https://regex101.com/r/CO7siv/1 In the example data, group 1 is always empty as the string starts with 3 digits. The negative lookahead after the newline will not succeed. Can you update the question with an example of the desired result?

Comment: The character ^ indicates beginning of line and $ indicates end of line.  You do not put the return characters into a Regex.  So use "^\d{3}.*:$"

Comment: @The fourth bird, sorry.. The back reference should be \2... It works OK in Regex Storm tester. But matches only one instance. As 123 was already consumed in the first instance.

Comment: @jdweng, I work with a single line, and am not sure about putting ^ and $. Usually the regex works fine.

Comment: Please provide a better example and also show us the desired output because now it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Trust me.  I've been working with Regex for a long time.

Comment: @Eddie Do you mean like this? `^(?=(\d{3})(.*:\r?\n)(?!\1)(\d{3}))` See the 3 capture group values https://regex101.com/r/N0rCk2/1

Comment: To answer the question, the -replace (regex) operator always a global replace, whether it's a string array or a raw string with line endings.

Comment: @js2010, yes, I understand that. But the replacement is always forward. The position is always at the end of the pattern consumed. And in this case it consumes the start part of the next replace.

Comment: Please edit the question and add a reproducible problem.

Comment: Edited. With an example. Thanks.

Comment: @The fourth bird... Yes. That works. I thought all groups in lookahead is not capturing ! Important lesson for me... Thanks so much .

Comment: I choose this as the answer.

Comment: @Eddie Did you mean the suggestion I added in the comments? That will not give you the desired replacement. In that way you can use `^(\d{3})\b.*:(?=\r?\n(?!\1)(\d{3})\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/wyG5AD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups where you can use the first group in a negative lookahead, and the second group to get the right result after replacing.

```
^(\d{3})\b.*:(?=\r?\n(?!\1)(\d{3})\b)
```

In the replacement use the full match and group 2:

```
$0\n   *** This value $2 ***
```

See a [.NET regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wyG5AD/1).

Output

```
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
   *** This value 123 ***
123 is different from:
   *** This value 567 ***
567.
```

---

If you want the *position* at the start of the string that asserts that the next line does not start with the digits at the start of the first line, the whole pattern will be in a positive lookahead assertion:

```
^(?=(\d{3}\b)(.*:\r?\n)(?!\1)(\d{3})\b)
```

See another [.NET regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/y898k7/1).

Answer (score 2):

Note that PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is *invariably* global, i.e. it *always* looks for and replaces *all* matches of the given regex.

Use the following `-replace` operation instead:

```
@'
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
123 is different from:
567.
'@ -replace '(?m)^(\d{3}) .+:(\r?\n)(?!\1)(?=(\d{3})\b)', 
            '$0  *** This value $3 ***$2'
```

<sup>Note: The `@'<newline>...<newline>'@` string literal used for the multiline input text is a so-called [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings).</sup>

Output:

```
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
  *** This value 123 ***
123 is different from:
  *** This value 567 ***
567.
```

- For a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/qllWQY/3), but in short:

  - `(?m)` is the inline form of the `Multiline` .NET regex option, which makes `^` and `$` match at the start and end of *each line*.
  - `^(\d{3})` therefore matches a 3-digit sequence only at the start of a line, in a capture group, and  `.+:` matches a space and at least one additional character on the same line all the way to a `:` at the end.
  - `(\r?\n)` captures the specific newline sequence encountered (which may be CRLF (Windows-format) or just LF (Unix-format)) in a 2nd capture group.

    - Capturing the specific newline sequence allows you to *replicate* it in the substitution string via placeholder `$2`, to ensure that the newly inserted line is terminated with the *same sequence*.
    - If you don't care about potentially mixing `\r\n` and `\n` in the resulting string, you could omit the 2nd capture group and use `` "`n" `` (sic) or `` "`r`n" `` instead, using an [*expandable* string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) with an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) - note that, unlike in C#,  `\r` and `\n` are *not* recognized in PowerShell string literals (it is only the .NET *regex engine* that recognizes them, but *not* in the *substitution operand* of `-replace`, which is *not* a regex, and where only `$`-prefixed placeholders are recognized).

      ```
      # Conceptually cleaner: separate the verbatim part from
      # the expandable part.
      ('$0  *** This value $2 ***' + "`n")

      # Alternative, using a single "..." string
      # The '$' chars. that are part of -replace *placeholders*
      # must be *escaped as `$* to prevent up-front expansion by PowerShell
      "`$0  *** This value `$2 ***`n"
      ```
  - `(?!\1)(?=(\d{3})\b)` uses *both* a negative (`(?!...)`) and positive (`?=...`) lookahead assertion to look for 3 digits at the start of the next line (at a word boundary, due to `\b`) that *aren't* the same as the 3 digits on the current line (`\1` being a *backreference* to what the 1st capture group matched).

    - Note that using a capture group *inside* an overall by-definition *non*-capturing lookaround assertion *is* possible, and indeed used above to capture the 3-digit sequence at the start of the *subsequent* line, referenced via placeholder `$3` in the substitution string.
  - In the substitution string, `$0`, `$2` and `$3` refer to the what the *entire* regex, the 2nd capture group, and the 3rd one captured, respectively (`$&` may be used in lieu of `$0`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more info about these placeholders).

    - Note that by using a *string* as the substitution operand, you are limited to embedding captured text *as-is*, via placeholders as such as `$0` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more info about these placeholders). If you need to determine the substitution text *fully dynamically*, i.e. if it needs to apply *transformations* based on each match:

      - In PowerShell (Core) 7+, you can use a script block `{ ... }` instead.
      - In Windows PowerShell, you'll have to call the underlying [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method directly.
    - See below.

---

To spell out the **fully dynamic substitution approach**, adding `1` to the captured number in this example:

[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution, using a script block (`{ ... }`) as `-replace`'s substitution operand:

```
@'
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
123 is different from:
567.
'@ -replace '(?m)^(\d{3}) .+:(\r?\n)(?!\1)(?=(\d{3})\b)', {
               '{0}  *** This value + 1: {1} ***{2}' -f $_.Value, ([int] $_.Groups[3].Value + 1), $_.Groups[2].Value
            }
```

*Windows PowerShell* solution, where a direct call to the underlying
[`[regex]::Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method is required:

```
$str = @'
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
123 is different from:
567.
'@

[regex]::Replace(
  $str, 
  '(?m)^(\d{3}) .+:(\r?\n)(?!\1)(?=(\d{3})\b)', 
  {
    param($m)
    '{0}  *** This value + 1: {1} ***{2}' -f $m.Value, ([int] $m.Groups[3].Value + 1), $m.Groups[2].Value
  }
)
```

Output (note that `1` has been added to each captured value):

```
111 is different from:
111 is different from:
  *** This value + 1: 124 ***
123 is different from:
  *** This value + 1: 568 ***
567.
```